# how to redirect to another view after authentication

Tags: php, angularjs, mysqli, ionic-framework

I m working with angularJS and php backend, and I try to make an authentication. I tested it by console.log, when the password is incorrect I get error message, and when the password is correct I don't get anything, in this case, I want to be riderected to other view, how can I do please:

app.js

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location,$state,$http,$window){

    $scope.submit = function()
    {
        data = {
            'NomClient' : $scope.NomClient,
            'mdp' : $scope.mdp
        };

        $http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
          // $window.location.href = '#/admin';
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
            console.log('error');
        });
    }

});
```

login.php

```
 <?php  

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  


 if(count($data) > 0)  
 { 
$NomClient=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->NomClient);
$mdp=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->mdp);


$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE NomClient = "'.$NomClient.'" AND   mdp= "'.$mdp.'"';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
        { 
            $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
            $_SESSION["naam"] = $NomClient; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'The username or password are incorrect!';
        }

}
 ?>
```

As you see, I have a comment line in app.js:  // $window.location.href = '#/admin'; I put it as comment because when I put it, it redirects me to admin view however the password is incorrect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: just try to use window.location.href

Comment: I use it, as you see in tho code, I put it as comment because when I put it it redirect me to other view however the password is wrong

Comment: what you need to do is from the php you need to send back the error message/Boolean value and check the data what is it coming and put the if condition

Comment: can you explain more! How can I do please!

Answer (score 0):

In the php file

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  
$response = array();

 if(count($data) > 0)  
 { 
$NomClient=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->NomClient);
$mdp=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->mdp);


$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE NomClient = "'.$NomClient.'" AND   mdp= "'.$mdp.'"';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
        { 
            $response["error"] = false;
            $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
            $_SESSION["naam"] = $NomClient; 
        }
        else
        {
            $response['error'] = true;
        }
  echoRespnse(200, $response);

}
function echoRespnse($status_code, $response)
{

    $app->contentType('application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
 ?>
```

app.js

```
 app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location,$state,$http,$window){

    $scope.submit = function()
    {
        data = {
            'NomClient' : $scope.NomClient,
            'mdp' : $scope.mdp
        };

        $http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)       .success(function(data)
        {
          console.log(data.error);
          if(data.error=="true") { 
              //Show error
           }else {
              //else redirect
         }

        })
        .error(function(data)
        {
            console.log('error');
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you , but I still have the same problem, always redirected however the password is wrong

Answer (score 0):

On Your php page

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
        { 
            echo 'success'; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'error';
        }

}
```

On your app.js

```
$http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
        .success(function(response)
        {
            if(response.data =='success'){
                  $window.location.href = '#/admin';
                  }else{
                    console.log('Username or Password Error');
                     }

            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
            console.log('error');
        });
```